# Error: Syntax error at 'Boolean'; expected ')' in Artifactory OSS Puppet Module

Tags: syntax-error, puppet, artifactory

Trying to use [this](https://forge.puppet.com/autostructure/artifactory) puppet module, it breaks with syntax error:

Error: Syntax error at 'Boolean'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/modules/artifactory/manifests/init.pp:6 on node artifactoryserver.openstacklocal

This is how I'm including it in the pp file:

```
node default { include '::artifactory' }
```

The line it refers is this [one](https://github.com/autostructure/artifactory/blob/master/manifests/init.pp#L6). Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of Puppet are you using?

Comment: What @DominicCleal means is that Types began to be supported in Puppet  4, so this is a strong indication that you are attempting to use this module with an obsolete version of Puppet (< 4.2.3).

Comment: Yes guys, the version was the error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MattSchuchard any chance you know of a way to install the puppet on the guest vm?